# PHP Mail function not working on Web Services

Tags: php, web-services

I am using two different servers for dev site and live site. My webservice function to send email confirmation is working on Dev Site but it is not working in Live Site. My 
email confirmation function is:

```
function getEmailConfirmation($UserName, $ChecklistID,$UserID,$AnswerBulkID, $TotalSubmitted){
    if ( ($UserID == '') || (!isset($UserID)) ) {
        return error("partial");
    }

    $entry = new Entry();   
    $entry_date_check = date('Y-m-d'); //for check if already
    $count_tbl_answers = $entry->listEntry("SELECT count(*) as total_from_answers FROM tbl_answers  where user_id='".$UserID."' and answer_bulk_id ='".$AnswerBulkID."' and date(ent_date) = '".$entry_date_check."' ");


    $to = "****@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "TDL Checklist email";
    $message = "Hello there! \n User ID: ".$UserID." \n User Name: ".$UserName."\n Check List ID: ".$ChecklistID."\n Answer Bulk ID: ".$AnswerBulkID;
    $from = "TLD-Email-Confirmation";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;


    if(($count_tbl_answers[0]['total_from_answers']) == $TotalSubmitted){

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);   

        $result = array(

                "user_id" => $UserID,
                "user_name"    => $UserName,
                "check_list_id"  => $ChecklistID,
                "answer_bulk_id"  => $AnswerBulkID,
            );

    } else{

         $delete_bulk = $entry->query("delete FROM tbl_answerbulk WHERE user_id ='".$UserID."' and check_list_id ='".$ChecklistID."' and id ='".$AnswerBulkID."'  ");

         $delete_answer = $entry->query("delete FROM tbl_answers WHERE user_id='".$UserID."'  and answer_bulk_id ='".$AnswerBulkID."'  ");

        return error("custom","","Could not submit your answer this time. Please try again later.");

    }

    $message = json_encode(
                $result
                );

    $fin_data['response'] = json_encode(array('Message'=>'ok','Data'=>$message));
    return $fin_data;

}
```

This function works perfectly on dev server, but it does not work on live server. What might be the reason?

**Note:**
Although mail function not working on Live site, it returns the result array which is just after the mail function.
That is:

```
    @mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);  

    $result = array(

            "user_id" => $UserID,
            "user_name"    => $UserName,
            "check_list_id"  => $ChecklistID,
            "answer_bulk_id"  => $AnswerBulkID,
        );
```

I also tried  `ini_set('smtp_port', 587);` and `@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` but does not worked.

Comment: Are dev and live both running on the same box? If not, does the live server have the mail function installed? A sysadmin may have also disabled mail on the live server if you do not manage it.

Comment: Live server is managed by clients. Is there any way to check if disabled or not?

Comment: What error do you get on the live server - also check the logs

Comment: It does not show any error.. If I use `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` it does not return anything but if I use `@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);` it returns an array which is just after the mail function. Further, `else` case works perfectly in both cases..

Comment: Your mail functionality appears to be unprotected! The server could be used to send millions of spam emails from the live server without you knowing, as a result the servers IP will be marked a spam. I suggest fixing promptly.

Comment: The '@' pre-pending any method call, suppresses errors - thats not what you want

Comment: What about the error log?

Comment: How to check error log in live server?

Comment: If the server is managed by a client, you may need to ask them for access to the logs.